# Pull a list of json objects with a Reference ID - MongoDB and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Similar questions have been asked before but i have not been able to pull a workable solution out from the responses, so excuse my ignorance here. I am just learning this stuff.

I have a schema setup

```
let movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  Title:{type: String, required:true},
  description: {type: String, required:true},
  genre: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Genre'}],
  director: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Director'}],
  Actors: [String],
  imageUrl: String,
  featured: Boolean
});
```

Corresponding Genre Schema

```
let genreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  description: String
});
```

Then I am trying to use an endpoint and pull all movies that contain that genre ID. i get no errors just a blank result.

```
app.get('/movies/:genre',  passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res) => {
  Movies.find({ genre:req.params.genre })
    .then((movies) => {
      res.status(201).json(movies);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});
```

For testing a request i would use something like /movies/609eab2d182950cee2ca2383

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the working method is as follows.

```
app.get('/movies/:genre',  passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res) => {
  const genre = req.params.objectID;
  Movies.find({ 'genre.type':genre })
    .then((movies) => {
      res.status(201).json(movies);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});
```

And now it works!

Answer (score 0):

The query is incorrect, what you are doing right now says that the field genre should be equal id that you got in params. You need to re-write it. Try this.

```
  Movies.find({ 'genre.type' : req.params.genre })
    .then((movies) => {
      res.status(201).json(movies);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Ayzrian for the comment, makes sense but still returning no results, again no error just an empty result.

Comment: try `'genre._id' : req.params.genre`

Comment: Also do you have entries in database with provided genres?